# How can I resolve this " TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'datetime.time' objects"

Tags: python-2.7, datetime

[image]

The image above shows my data set. I want to add 'DATE'(string) and 'SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE'(datetime) and form data in a single column. While I am doing this using:

```
DST = pd.to_datetime(flights_drop_null['DATE'] + ' ' + flights_drop_null['SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE_FINAL'])
flights_drop_null.insert(loc=5,column='DATE_SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE',value=DST)
```

I get that error.

Comment: sorry mate. I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Use [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) to convert the datetime to a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you are trying to combine disparate types.  You cannot joint a string with a datetime.time object simply because there isn't just one way to format your time object, you could print it as HH, or HH:MM or HH:MM:SS, etc.

If all you need in the end is to have that data in a single column to display, then I would recommend you convert the datatime.time object to a string.  If, however, you want to perform logic on the combined date and time, then I would suggest you convert the date string into a datetime.date object and then combine those two together into a datetime.datetime object.

By the way, I do not know what your `pd.to_datetime()` function does, so I'm just going to ignore it for now.

## Converting to a string

```
departure_time = flights_drop_null['SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE_FINAL']
DST = flights_drop_null['DATE'] + ' ' + departure_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
flights_drop_null.insert(loc=5,column='DATE_SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE',value=DST)
```

## Converting to a datetime

Well, I'm sure there are more clever ways, but the quickest I can prototype is to first convert to a string, then convert back to a datetime object.

```
import datetime
departure_time = flights_drop_null['SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE_FINAL']
DST = flights_drop_null['DATE'] + ' ' + departure_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
departure_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(DST, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```